# How to eagerload an array of values from a belongsTo relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables representing a many to many (belongsToMany) relationship between `User` and `Group` and `GroupUser` as the pivot table. What I would like to do is simply display all users that are **NOT** a member of `group_id 2`.

```
User model    GroupUser model (pivot table)      Group model

ID|name         ID|user_id|group_id            ID|group_name
1 |Mark          1| 1     |2                    1| the sharks
2 |Sam           2| 3     |1                    2| the tigers
3 |Sally         3| 2     |3                    3| the whales
4 |Tim           4| 4     |2
```

**My solution** 
Create a belongsTo (hasMany) relationship between User and GroupUser so GroupUser belongsTo User and then eager load all users that are not a member of group_id 2.

**How would I go about writing the code in my controllers and viewing this in blade?**

Before I use the WhereNotIn condition I'm trying to simply eager load all users. So far I have this but for some reason it's only reading the last line in the group_user table.

```
     foreach (GroupUser::with('belongstomethod')->get() as $query)
{
     $query->belongstomethod->name;
}
```

The result from the code above is Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will display all the users that are not part of group_id = 2.

Controller or repository:

```
$group_id = 2;
$users = User::whereHas('groups',function($query) use($group_id) {
    $query->where('id','!=',$group_id); 
})->get();

return view('your_view',compact('users')); //this will pass the $users collection to the view.
```

View (using blade):

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    {{$user->name}}
    {{$user->etc}}
@endforeach
```

- This code assumes you have a public method called "groups" on your User Model. And that the method returns a belongsToMany relationship.